# Python - Error Caused by Space in argv Arument

Tags: python, arguments

I had a Python program, running under Mint,that called another:-

```
repoCmd = 'Purchaser.py task ' + repoTask + ' "' + LastDataPath +'"'
os.system(repoCmd)
```

The quotes around LastDataPath were need as some directory names had spaces – typically christian name and surname, The problem was that although errors from the called program went to a logfile the wx.MessageDialog box was, obviously not displayed.

I have now changed the program so that it does not do a system call to:

```
SWCore.main(repoCmd)
```

However the problem with the spaces in the directory name have resurfaced as:-

```
def main(args):
    orig = sys.argv
    sys.argv = args.split()
```

recognises splits on the space between the quotes. Whilst I could code around the typical example I need a more general solution in case there is more than one space, e.g. “/home/user/data/James fforbes Smythe” or “/home/user/data/XYZ Bank/John Smith”

Comment: use `shlex.split()` instead.

Comment: Have posted an alternative answer in the duplicate. @JeanFrancois