# split at double quotes in python

Tags: python, string, file

```
import shlex
fil=open("./demoshlex.txt",'r')
line=fil.readline()
print line
print shlex.split(line)
```

suppose my sting is as below in a text file

line1 :

```
asfdsafadfa "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'." is something
```

I want to split the line and form list as follows

```
[asfdsafadfa, "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'.", is something]
```

i tried using `shlex.split` but it gave me exception, putting code and exception

```
**Output:**
python basicshelx.py
asfdsafadfa "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'."

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "basicshelx.py", line 5, in <module>
print shlex.split(line)
File "/home/siddhant/sid/.local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
return list(lex)
File "/home/siddhant/sid/.local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
token = self.get_token()
File "/home/siddhant/sid/.local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
raw = self.read_token()
File "/home/siddhant/sid/.local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

Comment: have you tried `line.split('"')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python split string on quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603310/python-split-string-on-quotes)

Comment: nope, i need to extract the second part that has nested double quotes as a whole

Comment: have you tried `line.split('"', 1)`?

Comment: if your sampleinput is 1 line, why did you share it on 2 lines? or is it actualy 2 lines?

Comment: Your desired output list is invalid since it's missing a closing quote mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to split only on the first occurance of `"` and want to keep all `"` in the second element of your output list.

Here is an example using just standard libraries, no import needed:

```
result = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        # strip spaces and \n from the line
        line = line.strip()
        # split the line on "
        my_list = line.split('"')
        # only append first element of the list to the result
        result.append(my_list[0].strip())
        # rebuild the second part, adding back in the "
        remainder = '"' + '"'.join([a for a in my_list[1:]])
        # append the second part to the result
        result.append(remainder)
print(result)
```

output:

```
['asfdsafadfa', '"Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf \'0000000000000000000000000000000\'."']
```

or if you print the individual elements of the output list:

```
for e in result:
    print(e)
```

output:

```
asfdsafadfa
"Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'."
```

[Edit based on comment]

As per comments you can use `.split('"', 1)`, example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        # strip spaces and \n from the line
        line = line.strip()
        # split the line on " but only the fist one
        result = line.split('"', 1)
        # add in the " for the second element
        result[1] = '"' + result[1]
```

[Edit based on updated question and comment]

Comment from OP:

> I want only the quoted part i.e remove "is something" from that
>   element of result List and make it [2] element

As the question is updated with a trailing "is something" string on the input, which need to be omitted in the output, the example now becomes as follows:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        # strip spaces and \n from the line
        line = line.strip()
        # split the line on " but only the fist one
        result = line.split('"', 1)
        # add in the " for the second element, remove trailing string
        result[1] = '"{}"'.format(result[1].rsplit('"', 1)[0])
```

however a file is likely to contain multiple lines, if this is the case you need to build up a list of outputs, one output for each line. The example now becomes as follows:

```
result = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if '"' in line:
            # we can split the line on "
            line = line.strip().split('"', 1)
            if line[1][-1] == '"':
                # no trailing string to remove
                # pre-fix second element with "
                line[1] = '"{}'.format(line[1])
            elif '"' in line[1]:
                # trailing string to be removed with .rsplit()[0]
                # post- and pre-fix " for second element 
                line[1] = '"{}"'.format(line[1].rsplit('"', 1)[0])
        else:
            # no " in line, return line as one element list
            line = [line.strip()]
        result.append(line)

# result is now a list of lists
for line in result:
    for e in line:
        print(e)
```

Comment: it kindof worked, but i have more strings after the last " without any quotation, how can i remove them?
eg
asfdsafadfa "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'." is something...............
i want only the quoted part i.e remove" is something" from that element of result List and make it [2] element here

Comment: @SiddhantRustagi It works for your string given, and the output requested. If you have other expceptions, other inputs, and other output requests, then this is not clear in your question above.

Comment: instead of the convoluted split and join, why not use [`.split('"', 1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Thanks for the response i have edited the expected output and more precise input.

Comment: @MaartenFabré thnx for the hint i got the other part through rsplit

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to use `re`

```
s = '''asfdsafadfa "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'." is something'''''

pat = re.compile(
    r'''
    ^      # beginning of a line
    (.*?)  # first part. the *? means non-greedy
    (".*") # part between the outermost ", ("-included)
    (.*?)  # last part
    $      # end of a line
    ''', re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE)
```

> ```
> pat.match(s).groups()
> ```

```
('asfdsafadfa ',
 '"Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf \'0000000000000000000000000000000\'."',
 ' is something')
```

so in total this would become:

```
test_str = '''asfdsafadfa "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'." is something
asfdsafadfa "Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'."
asfdsafadfa Tabvxc avcxsdasaf sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'.
'''
def split_lines(filehandle):
    pat = re.compile(r'''^(.*?)(".*")(.*?)$''', re.DOTALL)
    for line in filehandle:
        match = pat.match(line)
        if match:
            yield match.groups()
        else:
            yield line

with StringIO(test_str) as openfile:
    for line in split_lines(openfile):
        print(line)
```

The first generator splits the open filehandle in different lines. Then it tries to split the line. If it succeeds, it yields a tuple with the different parts, otherwise it yields the original string.

In your actual programs you can replace the `StringIO(test_str)` with `open(filename, 'r')`

> ```
> ('asfdsafadfa ', '"Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf \'0000000000000000000000000000000\'."', ' is something')
> ('asfdsafadfa ', '"Tabvxc "avcx"sdasaf" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf \'0000000000000000000000000000000\'."', '')
> asfdsafadfa Tabvxc avcxsdasaf sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your original string seems badly quoted to start with.
You can escape quotes by preceding them with a \ like so :

```
my_var = "Tabvxc \"avcx\"sdasaf\" sadasfdf. sdsadsaf '0000000000000000000000000000000'."
```

You can then proceed with splitting it like so :

```
my_var.split('"')
```

Comment: i have a file with similar strings like this thats why its exactly as the readline printed in my output. I am kinda new so how would I go about replacing the 2nd 3rd 4th and 5th ' " ' or rather all double quotes except 1st and last one

Comment: also my_var is not as u say, its should start with asfdsafadfa  then "

Comment: @ChukUltima that actually doesn't produce the requested output.