# regex in python: Can you filter string by deliminator with exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, split, python-re

I am trying to parse a long string of 'objects' enclosed by quotes delimitated by commas. EX:

```
s='"12345","X","description of x","X,Y",,,"345355"'

output=['"12345"','"X"','"description of x"','"X,Y"','','','"345355"']
```

I am using split to delimitate by commas:

```py
s=["12345","X","description of x","X,Y",,,"345355"]
s.split(',')
```

This almost works but the output for the string segment ...,"X,Y",... ends up parsing the data enclosed by quotes to "X and Y". I need the split to ignore commas inside of quotes

[Split_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW70L.png)

Is there a way I can delaminate by commas except for in quotes?

I tried using a regex but it ignores the ...,,,... in data because there are no quotes for blank data in the file I'm parsing. I am not an expert with regex and this sample I used from [Python split string on quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603310/python-split-string-on-quotes). I do understand what this example is doing and not sure how I could modify it to allow parse data that is not enclosed by quotes.

Thanks!

[Regex_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSEq.png)

Comment: if you split by " (quote) instead of by , (comma) then it will split the string into a list with extra commas, then you can just remove all elements that are commas

Comment: @smcrowley thanks for commenting but this solution does not work. When you split by quote you are just removing the double quotes and replacing with single quotes with like you mentioned extra elements that are commas. You still end up with same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```py
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '"12345","X","description of x","X,Y",,,"345355"'

In [3]: pattern = r"(?<=[\",]),(?=[\",])"

In [4]: re.split(pattern, s)
Out[4]: ['"12345"', '"X"', '"description of x"', '"X,Y"', '', '', '"345355"']
```

##### Explanation:

- `(?<=...)` is a "positive lookbehind assertion". It causes your pattern (in this case, just a comma, "`,`") to match commas in the string only if they are preceded by the pattern given by `...`. Here, `...` is `[\",]`, which means "either a quotation mark or a comma".
- `(?=...)` is a "positive lookahead assertion". It causes your pattern to match commas in the string only if they are followed by the pattern specified as `...` (again, `[\",]`: either a quotation mark or a comma).
- Since *both* of these assertions must be satisfied for the pattern to match, it will still work correctly if any of your 'objects' begin or end with commas as well.

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar!

Answer (score 1):

split by " (quote) instead of by , (comma) then it will split the string into a list with extra commas, then you can just remove all elements that are commas

```py
s='"12345","X","description of x","X,Y",,,"345355"'

temp = s.split('"')
print(temp)
#> ['', '12345', ',', 'X', ',', 'description of x', ',', 'X,Y', ',,,', '345355', '']
values_to_remove = ['', ',', ',,,']

result = list(filter(lambda val: not val in values_to_remove, temp))

print(result)
#> ['12345', 'X', 'description of x', 'X,Y', '345355']
```

Comment: This is a good attempt but I need the original empty comma set. For context I am writing a simple python script to convert a list of strings into JSON file with field and value. The data section ...,,,... is supposed to simulate 2 empty entries which I need to record. Thanks again for the advise though.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all quotes with empty string.

```
s='"12345","X","description of x","X,Y",,,"345355"'
n = ''
i = 0
while i < len(s):
   if i >= len(s):
       break
   if i<len(s) and s[i] == '"':
       i+=1
       while  i<len(s) and s[i] != '"':
           n+=s[i]
           i+=1
       i+=1
    if i < len(s) and s[i] == ",":
       n+=", "
    i+=1
n.split(", ")
```

output: ['12345', 'X', 'description of x', 'X,Y', '', '', '345355']

Comment: Hi thanks for quick response. This solution does not work because when you replace all quotes with empty string you still end up splitting the data "X,Y" to 'X,Y' which gives you the same issue delaminating the quotes enclosed data to  'X and Y'.

Comment: I added updated answer, there might be a better way of doing it but this also works